# jQuery toggle glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

is there a way to avoid problems with jQuery's slideToggle()?

I have a horizontal-sliding menu when somebody hovers a link there'es slideToggling list beneath.

The point is when I hover my mouse over the link before jQuery loads -  everthing works just opposite way. The menu disappears when I hover and shows when the pointer is somewhere else. So menu is useless.

Here's jQuery code:

```
$('#nav li').hover(function(){
$(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
```

})

Maybe some coditionals, something like "if nav li hovered and ul is invisible then slidetoggle once again"? But I'm not sure how to write it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be sure here (independent of initial mouse position), you have to split your [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) to explicitly call [`.slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/sideDown/) on `mouseenter` and [`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) on `mouseleave`, like this:

```
$('#nav li').hover(function(){
  $(this).children('ul').slideDown();
}, function() {
  $(this).children('ul').slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Man. You're saving my life again. LOVE YOU!!! :D And by the way why aren't you working for Microsoft, Google etc.?!